# Java seekable video stream

Tags: java, sockets, http, stream

I'm trying made a simple video stream with Java.I got that play some mp4 video,but not all. On the other hand, I can't seek the stream when the video is playing(Tried in VLC and Chrome). I like to know: What problems does my code have?

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Xerver {
    protected void start() {
        ServerSocket s;
        Socket remote;
        OutputStream out;

        System.out.println("Webserver starting up on port 8080");
        try {
          // create the main server socket
          s = new ServerSocket(8080);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("Error: " + e);
          return;
        }

        System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
        for (;;) {
          try {
            // wait for a connection
            remote = s.accept();
            // remote is now the connected socket
            System.out.println("Connection, sending data.");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(remote.getInputStream()));
            FileInputStream fs;
            out = remote.getOutputStream();
            File file = new File("D:\\stream.mp4");
            out.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n".getBytes());
            out.write("Content-Type: video/mp4\r\n".getBytes());
            out.write("Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n".getBytes());
            out.write(String.format("Content-Length:%s\r\n\r\n",Long.toString(file.length())).getBytes());
            fs = new FileInputStream(file);            
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            do{
                count = fs.read(buffer);
                out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            while (count <= 1024);
              out.flush();
              remote.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
          }

        }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
   Xerver ws = new Xerver();
    ws.start();
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You’re ignoring `in`.  It contains, among other things, the exact place to which you need to seek in your file.

Comment: I'm not sure how use it, can you help me if is possible?

Comment: Have you used a BufferedReader before?

Comment: No, I never had used before. I'm a noob working with files